# Locale files for unit test in Angular 5

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, internationalization

how do you solve missing locale from CLDR in angular 5 in unit tests?

I have in `app.module` `registerLocaleData(...)` and it works for the app, however when I run unit tests where I use pipes with locale, it doesn't know about `app.module`.

It sounds weird to load these locales in each test. I tried to import it in `test.ts` but with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue. Fixed it by modifying test.ts like so:

```
...
// Add these two imports
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';

...

getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

// Add this line to register a locale (german in this case).
registerLocaleData(localeDe);
```

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.. i’ll be trying this out shortly :-)